# Same Size for each cell in a grid

Tags: size, slds-grid

i would like to implement a **grid** for kind of eCommerce presentation . For that I need that all my **cells** in the grid have the same size but in every cells there is an image sometimes big sometimes small . how can i set one size for every cells ?

here is my code , a simple Lightning component with a grid

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
 <lightning:layout class="slds-page-header ">

 <div class="slds-grid  slds-gutters slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1 ">

  <div class="slds-col slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 top-buffer" hight="100">
    <lightning:card title="Bosch PRR 250ES" footer="test"  >
        <img src="https://www.ledico.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/hmprr003-300x151.png "/>      
        <lightning:button label="Add" class=" slds-button_brand slds-align_absolute-center" iconName="utility:add"/>
    </lightning:card>
  </div>

  <div class=" hvr-grow slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 top-buffer" hight="100" >
    <lightning:card title="Bosch PRR 250ES" footer="test"  >
        <img src="https://www.ledico.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/123132-300x229.png"/>
        <lightning:button label="Add" class=" slds-button_brand slds-align_absolute-center" iconName="utility:add"/>
    </lightning:card>
  </div>

  <div class="slds-col slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 top-buffer" hight="50">
    <lightning:card title="Bosch PRR 250ES" footer="test"  >
        <img src="https://www.ledico.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/65-179x300.png" hight="50"/>
        <lightning:button label="Add" class=" slds-button_brand slds-align_absolute-center" iconName="utility:add"/>
    </lightning:card>
  </div>

  <div class="slds-col slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 top-buffer">
    <lightning:card title="Bosch PRR 250ES"  >
        <img src="https://www.ledico.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/SPO3647323-300x300.jpg"/>
        <lightning:button label="Add" class=" slds-button_brand slds-align_absolute-center" iconName="utility:add"/>
    </lightning:card>
  </div>

  <div class="slds-col slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 top-buffer">
    <lightning:card title="Bosch PRR 250ES"  >
        <img src="https://www.ledico.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/p_k_gas_35_l_sfcplus_dynamik_v02_o_zubehoer-267x300.png"/>
        <lightning:button label="Add" class=" slds-button_brand slds-align_absolute-center" iconName="utility:add"/>
    </lightning:card>
  </div>
</div>

</lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Hello Raphael, welcome to SFSE. To get a better support, please refer to the guide [How do I ask a good question?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Also right now the question is quite open ended, would be nice if you could [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/253404/edit) your question and provide proper details along with some code.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply slds class to that cell and it will be displaying in iterative manner. Try by adding below style to your cell -

```
class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12"  //Set size according to device.
```

All items will be take equal width.

Comment: -1 for not providing some solution to problem which is not clear. a lot of things are possible with CSS, start closer to standard SLDS is better.